# how to create a camera form to save image and video in folder we want

Tags: windows-store-apps

i want to create a register form and user can take a photo or short video for their profile (save the infor in .json) in Windows Store. Somebody help me how to enable camera to take a photo and how to save the photo.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JXMy.png)

Comment: Are you have Windows 8.1 or UWP application?

Comment: i have both i want the camera seen will display in the place i want

Answer (score 0):

There are much examples in web.
First add to manifest

```
 <Capabilities>
<DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
</Capabilities>
```

Add to MainPage XAML:

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,10">
        <Button x:Name="btnStartPreview" Background="Gray" 
                                       Click="btnStartPreview_Click" Margin="0,0,0,0" Content="Start preview"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnTakePhoto" Background="Gray" 
                                      Click="btnTakePhoto_Click" Margin="10,0,0,0" Content="Take a photo"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid>
      <Image x:Name="captureImage" Width="400" Height="400" Visibility="Visible"/>
      <CaptureElement x:Name="previewElement" Width="400" Height="400" Visibility="Visible"/>
    </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

And in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using Windows.Media.Capture;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

MediaCapture mediaCapture;
bool isPreviewing = false;

        private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaCaptureInitializationSettings set = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
        set.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
        mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
        await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(set);
    }

        private async void btnStartPreview_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isPreviewing == false)
        {
            previewElement.Source = mediaCapture;
            await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
            isPreviewing = true;
        }
        previewElement.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

And inside btnTakePhoto_Click event

```
  btnTakePhoto.IsEnabled = false;
        btnStartPreview.IsEnabled = false;

        InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);

        stream.Seek(0); // текущую позицию потока устанавливаем в 0
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(stream);
        captureImage.Source = bitmap;
        if (isPreviewing == true) await mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
        isPreviewing = false;
```

Here is large example:
[Capture photos and video with MediaCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-mediacapture)